# I dont understand this output produced by selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, gettext

I'm trying to write an application for the game Path of Exile, that lists the items in my stash on trading websites automatically.

For this I have to retrieve the items in my stash from their website. For some reason the ".getText()" functions is behaving very weird on the website. I really can't see any mistakes I did with the x-path Expressions.

Example:
Here you can see a snippet from the HTML file I am working on

[screenshot of browser debugg tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMwAi.png)

In the screenshot you can see that the x-Path I am using is selecting a element with a text element, however when I iterate over the elements and get the text with the getText() function, it returns a empty String... I really have no clue what I am doing wrong, is it the website, that is denying me to access the field?

In case it helps I add here a screenshot of the source code for outputting the text fields

[printing the text of the elements(SourceCode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT3yy.png)

[5 empty Strings as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTZN3.png)

Comment: please add code and your error screenshot inline. Attaching images makes it difficult to read in single flow.

Comment: Also add the url and expected output.

Comment: Please add your source code directly into your question.

Answer (score -1):

On your place I would try to get value instead of text.

try to replace

```
e.getText()
```

with

```
e.getAttribute("value")
```

or you can also try to play with .getCssValue()